# I am looking to parse a large amount of emails from a public dataset, specifically emails from the late 90's or early 2000's with Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, email, coding-style

So basically I want to parse the Enron public emails data-set and I am uncertain about email formatting and types back in the day. I am unfamiliar with MIME types and those other formatting details. So I want to know if all emails have the same first couple lines and last couple lines.

I essentially want to get rid of everything but the body of emails. So I would also like to know whether it would be easier (not knowing what I know), to use the C method of parsing by lines or to essentially try to clean up all the emails to leave just want I need. I don't care too much about white space, but I am also not very skilled at regex or lexical parsing so if anyone has good references on refreshing regex or can breakdown probably the only rules that I'll probably need that would be great.

Comment: Have you seen the [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html) module in the standard library?

Comment: yes, so can you essentially take a file that cats with email info and pass that into an email object?

Comment: I believe so. See also [mailbox](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/mailbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's a whole lot of "...I don't knows..." with zero info about your objective. About the best advice I can offer is you read RFC-822. http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html

You're going to have to one up on Regex parsing if you are going to want to extract any meaningful info from the emails. I'd suggest the Oreilly book on regex, or reading over http://www.regular-expressions.info/

If you have more targeted questions it's possible SO could help you then

Good luck